# How can transform field names to work with existing API calls in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a Django app that needs to allow an existing API to make calls to it.

The existing API makes calls like:

**/api/product**

which expects fields named:

*product_id, heading, unit*

but the Django app returns fields named:

*product_id, title, unit*

Is there a way I can keep both ends happy but transforming the names during serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom ModelSerializer creating a heading filed name, and setting the source.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    heading = serializers.CharField(source='title')

    class Meta(object):
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'product_id',
            'heading',
            'unit')
```

Comment: Great. It worked fine, but I had to change 'title' to 'heading' in fields.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the fields, thank you for correcting it! :)